# Auth0: how to use User Profile in a rule?

Tags: auth0

I want to add `last_ip` and `last_login` as claims in the access token using a rule:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  const namespace = 'https://myapp.example.com/';
  context.accessToken[namespace + 'last_ip'] = user.last_ip;
  context.accessToken[namespace + 'last_login'] = user.last_login;
  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Those two properties does not exist on the user inside the rule: https://auth0.com/docs/rules/references/user-object

Neither on the context object: https://auth0.com/docs/rules/references/context-object

But they exists on the user profile: https://auth0.com/docs/users/references/user-profile-structure

**Q:** How can I use any user profile field I want inside a rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  const namespace = 'https://myapp.example.com/';  

  var ManagementClient = require('auth0@2.19.0').ManagementClient;
  var management = new ManagementClient({
    token: auth0.accessToken,
    domain: auth0.domain
  });  

  management.getUser(user.user_id)
    .then(function(users){
      context.accessToken[namespace + 'last_ip'] = users[0].last_ip;
      context.accessToken[namespace + 'last_login'] = users[0].last_login;

      callback(null, user, context);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      callback(err);
    });
}
```